# F#: Is it an idiomatic way to call functions with pipe against parentheses?

Tags: f#

If one have function like this:

```
let test arg func =
    func arg
```

Is it an idiomatic way to call it using pipe,

```
test 1 <| fun n -> n = 2
```

rather then to call it using parentheses?

```
test 1 (fun n -> n = 2)
```

And when one should not use pipe in a such way?

Comment: Idiomatic would be `fun n -> n=2 |> test 1` which makes type inference work better

Comment: I personally like `<|` but it's rather limited in F# as `<|` has too high precedence and is left-associative. Taking type-inference flow as @JohnPalmer said means `|>` is probably preferable.

Comment: Have you considered using a let to name your lambda? `let goodName n =  n = 2` and then `test 1 goodName` . It's often not a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

In my opinion, this is fine:

```
test 1 (fun n -> n = 2)
```

It may not compose well because of the order of the arguments, so further details follow below. These are options you can use if you need them.

## Details

I think it'd be more idiomatic to flip the arguments for the `test` function around:

```
let test' func arg = func arg
```

because this would enable you to write this expression instead:

```
1 |> test' (fun n -> n = 2)
```

If you can't change the signature of `test`, you can introduce [a `flip` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip):

```
let flip f x y = f y x
```

This function flips the arguments for a function, so that you can write this instead:

```
1 |> (flip test) (fun n -> n = 2)
```

In the example given here, that's making things more complicated than they have to be, so I'd most likely prefer one of the original suggestions:

```
test 1 (fun n -> n = 2)
```

Personally, I find that easier to understand than the backwards pipe, which always confuses me.

BTW, you can reduce the function in this particular example:

```
test 1 ((=) 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

[This snippet](http://fssnip.net/4o) by [Stephen Swensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236255/stephen-swensen) demonstrates a **high precedence, right associative backward pipe**, `(^<|)`.

```
let inline (^<|) f a = f a
```

This single-liner from the linked page demonstrates how to use it:

```
{1..10} |> Seq.map ^<| fun x -> x + 3
```

And here is an example how to use it for multi-line functions. I find it most useful for real-world multi-liners as you no longer need to keep closing parenthesis at the end:

```
myCommands
|> List.map ^<| fun command ->
    let returnValue = manipulate command
    doSomethingElse()
    returnValue
```

Yet another benefit is keeping the natural order of arguments which often helps you avoid extra type annotations. In the snippet above, the type for `command` is inferred automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a strong preference for one over the other.

Personally I'd use parens for a one-liner like your example:

```
test 1 (fun n -> n = 2)
```

and pipeline if `func` has multiple lines - this way you don't need the awkward closing paren that you have to move around as you change the function's body:

```
test 1 <| fun n -> 
    let x = n + 1
    x = 3
```